# Read Smart Contract ContractABI error message?

Tags: contract-debugging

Anyone know what causeses Read Smart Contract ContractABI error message? 
https://etherscan.io/token/0x983f6d60db79ea8ca4eb9968c6aff8cfa04b3c63#readContract

[image: Do you know what causes ContractABI error message?]

Answer (score 1):

If you go here (https://etherscan.io/address/0x983f6d60db79ea8ca4eb9968c6aff8cfa04b3c63) which is the address of the smart contract for the token you're looking at, you can see under the 'Contract' tab that no source code has been posted to Etherscan for that address (all you see is the bytecode).

In order for Etherscan to know the ABI, it must have been given either the source code (from which it can derive the ABI) or, if not the source code, then at least the ABI definition. Since neither of those two things has been "uploaded" or "published" to Etherscan, Etherscan cannot report on the token.